# Move and resize windows while holding keys down

Tags: windows-10, window-manager

I am aware of all of the window snapping features of Windows 10, which all work very well.

However, I am after a simple feature I used to enjoy via a third party on a Mac. While holding down a pre-defined hotkey, I would like to be able to resize or move a window that is currently under the cursor.

For example - if I want to resize my Chrome window, I just want to hover over it, hold down a hotkey and then mouse movement should translate into the window changing size.

Is there a tool that could provide this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to resolve this with [AltDrag](https://stefansundin.github.io/altdrag/). Still requires a mouse button to be held down but that's close enough!